# Regsvr error message when trying to register ISDone.dll and unarc.dll

Tags: regsvr32

Hye... I'm using Windows 10, 64-bit and i was trying to register ISDone.dll and unarc.dll, and an error message popped out, saying that:

```
'The module "C:/Windows/SysWoW64/ISDone.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found. Make sure that "C:/Windows/SysWoW64/ISDone.dll" is a valid Dll or Ocx file and then try again.
```

I have placed the ISDone.dll and unarc.dll in both System32 and SysWoW64.